# Ошибка No module named 'IQ_rc` в Qt Designer

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qrc

Сделал в *Qt Designer* макет для приложения, конвертировал файл **`interface.ui`** в **`test.py`**, но при запуске **test.py** обнаружил ошибку вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не могу понять, что это за модули и раз уж они создались, то для чего?  
Лишь по их названиям могу сказать, что когда я создавал `pushButton` в одном из `tabWidget` окне, мне надо было вложить в них картинки и приходилось для этого создавать специальные файлы расширения **`.qrc`**,  чтобы благодаря им поместить картинку в `PushButton`.

Вот как это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я попробовал убрать эти импорты и оно запустилось, но без картинок и со сбитым интерфейсом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Кто может подсказать, буду рад любой помощи.

Весь код большой, поэтому я взял только те места где использую эти картинки. 
Если что картинки находятся в той же директории, что и файлы **interface.ui** и **test.py**.

Вот упрощенный код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.setEnabled(True)
        Form.resize(599, 569)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(Form)
        self.tabWidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 601, 571))
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/newPrefix/MAIN.png);\n"
"font: 11pt \"Times New Roman\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 127);\n"
"\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")

.................

self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 211, 161))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/newPrefix/Темпераметр.jpg);")
        self.pushButton_4.setText("")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 200, 211, 141))
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/newPrefix/stress.jpg);")
        self.pushButton_5.setText("")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 350, 211, 161))
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/newPrefix/IQ.jpg);")
        self.pushButton_6.setText("")

..................

import IQ_rc
import MAIN_rc
import Stres_rc
import spr_rc
import temp_rc
import test_rc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам не надо создавать отдельные файлы ресурсов для каждой картинки.
Создайте один файл, например `my_resources.qrc` и туда добавьте все изображения.

После чего у вас появится файл `my_resources.qrc` а в нем:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource prefix='/'>
  <file>img/lena.png</file>
  <file>img/pyqt.jpg</file>
  <file>img/red.png</file>
  <file>img/bad.png</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

у меня изображения лежат в папке `img` у вас `newPrefix`.

Далее вы конвертируете `.ui` в `.py`

**ВАЖНО**! Далее вы конвертируете `.qrc` в `.py`

```
pyrcc5 my_resources.qrc -o my_resources_rc.py
```

и полученный `my_resources_rc.py` у вас импортируется `import my_resources_rc`

Вот после этого можете запускать приложение.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.setEnabled(True)
        Form.resize(599, 569)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(Form)
        self.tabWidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 601, 571))
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/img/lena.png);\n"
"background-position: center;\n"
"background-repeat: no-reperat;\n"
"font: 11pt \"Times New Roman\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 127);\n"
"\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")

#.................

        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)                                       # + ?

        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)  #(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 211, 161))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("""QPushButton {
        background-image: url(:/img/pyqt.jpg);
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-reperat;
        }""")  # background-image:

#        self.pushButton_4.setText("")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)  #(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 200, 211, 141))
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/img/red.png); background-repeat: no-reperat;background-position: center;")  
        self.pushButton_5.setText("")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)  #(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 350, 211, 161))
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/img/bad.png); background-repeat: no-reperat;background-position: center;")  
        self.pushButton_6.setText("")

#..................

import my_resources_rc
#import IQ_rc
#import MAIN_rc
#import Stres_rc
#import spr_rc
#import temp_rc
#import test_rc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!!